# MongoDB lookup ObjectID when the collection it belongs to is unknown?

Tags: mongodb

The software I am currently working with can only run aggregate queries or simple find_one's. I am new to mongodb ,so I am having difficulty figuring out if I can do what I would like to do.

**The Question:**
Is it possible to run a lookup query on an object id when that object id may be in one of many collections?

**The setup:**
I have a main collection, this main collection is essentially an array of other ObjectID's that apply to this object. This collection (call it Main_Config) consists of three ObjectID's.

1. Client
2. General_Config
3. Role_Config

The Client, `General_Config`, and `Main_Config` can all have an enforced schema I would like the `Role_Config` to also have an enforced schema. This is where the issue comes into play, the `Role_Config`, may take 3 or more possible schemas. My idea was to create a collection for every possible schema, however if I do this I will not know to what collection the `Role_Config` `ObjectID` belongs to. Is there a way to lookup an `ObjectID` that may exist in one of many collections?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `findInAnyCollection()` type of function.  In your model you will have to manually code a loop and look it up.

One approach:  In your main config collection, we have docs with this field:

```
    otherIds = [ {coll: "ROLE", key: "5fb8057f08c09fb8dfe8d310"}, {coll: "GENERAL", key: "GENERAL_72f2b2922ed98800bd0e"}, ...]
```

Putting it all together:

```
db.AA.drop();
db.BB.drop();
db.CC.drop();

db.AA.insert({_id:0, otherIds: [ {coll:"BB", key:0}, {coll:"BB", key:1}, {coll:"CC", key:2}]});

db.BB.insert({_id:0, foo:"bar", baz:"bin"});
db.BB.insert({_id:1, foo:"ion", baz:"kjlkj"});
db.BB.insert({_id:2, foo:"POPPO", baz:"UHUH"});
db.CC.insert({_id:0, data: "wfwefw"});
db.CC.insert({_id:1, data: "jj"});
db.CC.insert({_id:2, data: "mm"});

doc = db.AA.findOne();
doc['otherIds'].forEach(function(item) {
        var other = db[item['coll']].findOne({_id:item['key']});
        printjson(other);
    });
```

Comment: Would it be possible to set the `coll` keys value equal to a variable that can be passed in as the `from` value in a lookup?

Comment: Expanding the answer.